# Polchinski Equation (10.4.7)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory

I'm having a problem to interpret eq. (10.4.7) in Polchinski:

$$
\gamma(z)\delta(\gamma(0)) = O(z), \qquad \beta(z)\delta(\gamma(0)) = O(z^{-1}).
$$

What does he mean by $\delta$? He tries to explain after but I cannot understand. What are the precise step to go from eq (10.4.3a) to (10.4.7)?

Comment: Please phrase the question in a way such that it is understandable for someone who does not have access to Polchinski.

Comment: I would be helpful to add his explanation that you don't understand so that answerers could help elucidate the intended meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator $\delta(\gamma(z))$ is meant to be the operator dual to the state $|0\rangle_{NS}$ according to the state-operator correspondence. One could call it $E(z)$ or anything like that.

But Polchinski uses the notation $\delta(\gamma(z))$ with this "nested" structure because the operator described in the previous paragraph may also be interpreted as the Dirac delta-function whose argument is another operator, $\gamma(z)$. Why?

Because the delta-function obeys
$$\delta(x) x = 0$$
It's only nonzero at the point where $x=0$, so if you multiply it by $x$, the product is zero everywhere. Now, substitute $\gamma(0)$ for this $x$ and you will formally get
$$\delta(\gamma(0)) \gamma(0) = 0$$
You also want to know if the values of $z$ are different.
$$\delta(\gamma(0)) \gamma(z) = ?$$
The result has to be something that is equal to $0$ for $z=0$, as argued previously. There is no branch cut etc. so the right hand side may be expanded in power series, and because it's zero at zero, it may be written as $O(z)$.

The two conditions in (10.4.7) are nothing else than translations of the two conditions in (10.4.3a) from the cylinder to the plane, i.e. according to the state-operator dictionary. As I said, replace the state $|0\rangle_{NS}$ by the $\delta$ operator. And multiply it either by the Fourier modes of $\beta$ or those of $\gamma$. The point is that the state zero or the operator $\delta$ is annihilated when multiplied by a "high enough" mode of $\beta$ or $\gamma$. The "high enough modes" are described by the inequalities in (10.4.3a).

When you translate it to the plane and take the conformal weights of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, namely $+3/2$  and $-1/2$ into account – they correspond to the "shift" of the powers when going from the cylinder to the plane – you get (10.4.7).

On the cylinder (states), $\beta_k$ modes are multiplied by $\exp(2ik\sigma)$; on the plane, they are multiplied by $z^{k+3/2}$ or something like that. Sorry if the signs are wrong, you may fix them. The claim $\beta_k$ with $k$ greater than something annihilates the $|0\rangle_{NS}$ state gets translated to the claim that a power law expansion having just $\beta(z)$ multiplied by high enough powers of $z$, when multiplied by the operator $\delta(\gamma(z))$, only yields a power law expansion with powers of $z$ greater than some constant, and you may verify that the minimum exponents are exactly what is written there.

Comment: As an aside question, I was asking if in the bc system 
$$
b(z)b(0) = O(z)
$$
or it is just 0. I tried to compute
1) With eom, using eq (2.5.6b) by Plochinki, removing the source $\delta\rightarrow 0$
2) Using mode expansion
and I get precisely 0. Maybe I'm missing something. 
If it would not be zero, for instance, how to compute the OPE
$$
:b\partial^7b::bc:?
$$

Comment: Dear MaPo, the product of the two operators is surely not equal to zero. Just map it to the cylinder, if the plane distracts you. $b(\sigma_1) b(\sigma_2)$ is just a product of two anticommuting operators, right? Why should it be zero? It is $O(z)$ indeed because there's no singularity for $z\to 0$ and the value for $z=0$ is zero due to anticommutation. But for $z\neq 0$, it cannot be zero.

Comment: You are probably confused by the difference between the $=$ sign in the OPEs, and the sim sign $\sim$. The latter indicates that the right hand side only lists the singular terms, i.e. is correct up to additive terms $+O(1)$.

Comment: Similarly, the OPE you are asking for is not "equal" to zero, but it is $\sim 0$ because the OPEs had no singular terms to start with, so one couldn't have gotten any singular terms by differentiation, either. But again, $b(\sigma_1) \partial_\sigma^7 b(\sigma_1) b(\sigma_2)c(\sigma_2)$ has no reason to be zero, has it?